# What are the valid WCF MSMQ method return types?

Tags: wcf

For some reason, all the examples I find on WCF MSMQ show void as the return type of the method.  Is this just coincidence?  If not, why?   What are the valid return types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no valid Return types for sending to to a WCF service on an MSMQ end point.

Because you are writing to a queue and not directly communicating with the service the communication channel is not available for the service to send a response. Additionally one of the major benefits of writing to the queue is that the service may not even be running at the point the message is sent, the message will get picked up once the service becomes active again.

If no exception is thrown whilst sending to the service then you know that the message has at the very least been added to the message queue.